# Custom endpoint filtering post by custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rest-api, endpoints, request-filter

I am trying to create a custom endpoint by custom taxonomies, I have already created another for the categories and it works well, however there is something I cannot solve with this

```php
function get_latest_posts_by_term($request) {

    $args = array(
            'term' => $request['term_id']
    );

    $posts = get_posts($args);
    if (empty($posts)) {
    return new WP_Error( 'empty_term', 'There are no posts to display', array('status' => 404) );

    }

    $response = new WP_REST_Response($posts);
    $response->set_status(200);

          $data = [];
          $i = 0;

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $data[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
        $data[$i]['title'] = $post->post_title;
        $data[$i]['excerpt'] = $post->post_excerpt;
        $data[$i]['date'] = $post->post_date;
        $data[$i]['content'] = $post->post_content;
        $data[$i]['slug'] = $post->post_name;
        $data[$i]['author'] = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author);
        $data[$i]['category'] = get_the_category( $post->ID);  
        $data[$i]['theme'] = get_the_terms($post->ID,'theme');
        $data[$i]['Rute-geografic'] = get_the_terms($post->ID,'rute-geografice');
        $data[$i]['featured_image']['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID, 'thumbnail');
        
        $data[$i]['post_tags'] = get_the_terms($post->ID,'post_tag');
        
        
        
        $i++;
    }

    return $data;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
register_rest_route( 'wl/v1', 'posts/term/(?P<term_id>\d+)',array(
                'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'get_latest_posts_by_term'
      ));
    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!!! A friend of my found the way

````
function get_latest_posts_by_term($request) {

    $parsed_args=[
    'numberposts'      => 20,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array (
            'taxonomy' => $request['slug'],
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $request->get_param('name'),
        )
    ),
    ];
    
    $get_posts = new WP_Query;
    $posts= $get_posts->query( $parsed_args );
    //$posts = get_posts($args);
    if (empty($posts)) {
    return new WP_Error( 'empty_terms', 'There are no posts to display', array('status' => 404) );
    }

    $response = new WP_REST_Response($posts);
    $response->set_status(200);

          $data2 = [];
          $i = 0;

    foreach($posts as $post) {
        $data2[$i]['id'] = $post->ID;
        $data2[$i]['title'] = $post->post_title;
        $data2[$i]['excerpt'] = $post->post_excerpt;
        $data2[$i]['date'] = $post->post_date;
        $data2[$i]['content'] = $post->post_content;
        $data2[$i]['slug'] = $post->post_name;
       
        $i++;
    }

    return $data2;
}

add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
 register_rest_route( 'wl/v1', 'posts/terms/(?P<slug>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)',array(
                'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => 'get_latest_posts_by_term'
      ));
    
});```
````